# Testing Using the Sandbox and non developers

Tags: button, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am at the stage where I need to have some users test my PayPal process.
I have created Sandbox ID's for them. 
I am using the IPN interface for my backend notification of payments, etc.

What I need to do is have these other people that are helping test the process be able to press the pay now button (which is a Custom button) go to the PayPal Sandbox and make the payment.

It seems that they will need to be logged in to do this.
I can't give them the account credentials for the master account.
So, how do I do this testing?

Answer (score 0):

The developer account has to be linked to a live PayPal account.  When you are using Website Payments Standard or Express Checkout, the buyer would have to log into the developer account first before they could complete a payment with their sandbox buyer account.  One option would be to set up a personal paypal account, that uses an email address that you have not used on your other PayPal accounts.  You do not need to add any type of financial infomration to this account, just keep it as bare and simple as possible.  Then you can link that account to a new developer account.  Once you have the account linked to the new developer account, you can create a new test sandbox buyer account on that developer account.  Then you can let the person who is testing your buyer experience have access to that developer account.  It will be linked to a real PayPal account, but it will only be a personal paypal account with not financial information on it.

Comment: Chad, In your explanation, you say to set up a Personal PayPal account.  I assume that this is a "LIVE" account on the Live PayPal system.  Is that correct?
Then, that personal email account is supposed to use an email address that I have not used on my other PayPal accounts.
Which other PayPal accounts?  Live system or sandbox, or both?
YOu then say to link that account to a New Developer account.
I assume I need to create a new Developer Account.  Is that correct?  How do I link that personal account to the new Developer Account?  Would appreciate more detail on your suggestion.

Comment: Correct, you would need to create a live personal account using an an email address that you do not have on other live PayPal accounts.  Then once you have this set up, you will need to go to developer.paypal.com and create a new developer account.  You will use your new live personal account, that you just created.  Then once you have your developer account created, you will then need to create test sandbox seller and buyer accounts to test with.